# Rename line/elements in C

Tags: c

I'm programming in C and I need some help:
I' have a bidimensional vector ( n rows, 2 columns) and each rows represent the coordinates of an Element I want to put in a bigger bidimensional vector, something like battleship. Is it possible to give a name to each rows? For example, how can I give the name X to the first element of my smaller vector?

What I've to do is: the element in vector represents coordinate of an element in a bigger vector, so each rows represent an element. I compare to at once, and if their are neighbors and one of them is "X", also the other one become an "X" element.
Something like that:

```
enter code here
int x,y;
for(int a=0; a<nbE; a++)                         
   {    
    for(int i=1; i<n;i++)                      
       {
           x=vector[a][0]-vector[i][0];

                   if((x==1)||(x==-1)||(x==0))
          {
            y=vector[a][1]-vector[i][1];

            if( (y==1)||(y==-1)||(y==0))
              { 
                if (vector[a]="X")             *That's the point*
                   vector[i]="X";
              }  
          }     
       }          
   .......
   }
```

Comment: If you are programming in c, use the [tag:c] tag, if you are programming in c#, use the [tag:c#] tag. These are completely different languages.

Comment: You're familiar with *pointers*, right?

Comment: Please add a minimal complete verifiable example

Comment: @JHBonarius Use `[mcve]` for a quick link: [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new here, is it ok now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485124/841108 is very related. In reality, all C (and C++) arrays are monodimensional.

Answer (score 0):

In C this is not directly possible, however.

A tricky (thus **not** recommended) approach does exist:

```
#define X (vector[0][0])
```

Now you're able to use `X` anywhere to resemble `vector[0][0]`.

If you migrate your project to C++ then reference will be available, providing a natural way to do so.

Comment: Is it the only solution? @iBug