# how to scan a 2d array using a function without deleting it's content

Tags: c, arrays, function

as a homework assignment, i need to scan N matrices and a user input integer, and scan if any of the matrices values contains that number
without using pointers.

as soon as i finish scanning the array and exits the function, the content of the array resets to zero, or trash if i dont init the array.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include<stdio.h>

#define N 2

int exist(int matrix[][N], int elem);

void input_matrix(int matrix[][N], int size);


void main()
{
    int matrix_1[][N] = { 0 }, matrix_2[][N] = { 0 }, matrix_3[][N] = { 0 };

    int elem;
    printf("please enter values of squared matrix:\n");
        input_matrix(matrix_1[][N], N);
        //(input_matrix(&matrix_2[N][N]));
    //  (input_matrix(&matrix_3[N][N]));
    printf("please enter number to search for in the matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &elem);
    if (exist(matrix_1,elem))
        //printf("exist.");//the next part of h.w to be written when input func works

}

void input_matrix(int matrix[][N], int size)//something here fishy
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
int exist(int matrix[][N], int elem)
{
    int i, j;
    int flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if ((matrix[i][j]) == elem)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Try `for (j = 0; j < size; j++)` --> `for (j = 0; j < N; j++)`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how many rows there are when you initialize your arrays like `matrix_1[][N] = { 0 };`. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346426/omitting-sizes-while-initializing-c-c-multidimensional-arrays). The compiler counts the number of subarrays to determine the first dimension of the array.

Comment: You can do it without any variables declared with explicit pointer declaration syntax, which I guess is what you're after, but you cannot do it without using pointers at all.  The indexing operator (`[]`) is a *pointer* operator, after all, and you cannot receive an array as a function parameter, even if the declaration syntax disguises that.

Comment: The compiler *does* know how many rows, @QuaxtonHale.  There are just enough to accommodate all the elements of the initializer, which is 1.  That's not what the OP appears to want, but there's no uncertainty.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is right. I meant to point out OP's intent.

Answer (score 3):

1. Inside the main function, in the call `input_matrix(matrix_1[][N], N)` you pass the invalid parameter. Instead should pass the *whole matrix*, like `input_matrix(matrix_1, N)`.
2. As noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468376/how-to-scan-a-2d-array-using-a-function-without-deleting-its-content#comment101411017_57468376), it will be better to declare matrix like `matrix_1[N][N]`.